# 'for_each_n' is not a member of 'std' in C++17

Tags: c++, foreach, c++17

I have small piece of code for `std::for_each_n` loop. I tried running it on inbuilt [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) compiler GCC  C++17 using following command :

```
g++ -std=c++1z -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

But compiler give an error that **" 'for_each_n' is not a member of 'std' ".**

My code is bellow which is copied from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ns{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto n: ns) std::cout << n << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::for_each_n(ns.begin(), 3, [](auto& n){ n *= 2; });
    for (auto n: ns) std::cout << n << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

So, Why I'm getting an error?

Comment: does you compiler support c++17?

Comment: @tobi303 I used http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ compiler

Comment: And is this particular feature supported?

Comment: The default for Coliru is to use C++14. Did you remeber to change the compiler flag?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I used g++ -std=c++1z -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

Comment: @tobi303 That link isn't sharing what the OP compiled.  It is just a link to coliru,

Comment: @NathanOliver haha, I definitely need more coffee

Comment: @rsp : TL;DR: Your code is fine, libstdc++ doesn't have `for_each_n` yet. Clang trunk + libc++ [works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kZZ7Xo7gCtZBYm48).

Comment: @ildjarn if you have a quote supporting this, you have the perfect answer.

Comment: @stefaanv : I have empirical evidence from testing GCC and Clang trunks. Nothing authoritative, hence just a comment. ;-]

Comment: Yes, standard library implementations need to catch up to the standard. This question and any subsequent answers will likely be wrong in a very short time. I think it should be closed, but I can't figure out the appropriate reason to vote against.

Comment: Can we just get an authoritative "it isn't implemented yet?" Q/A.

Comment: Well, [tag:C++1z] != [tag:C++17] except on SO ;)

Comment: FWIW, gcc 8.1.0 has `-std=c++17` **and** `-std=c++2a`, and still does balk at `for_each_n`. You would think it is easy enough to implement...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.  The issue is that libstdc++ does not support `std::for_each_n` until GCC 8 and Clang 8. If we look at the [header](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4a15d84228ee29d55cd011094f82c8d4fa9a5a76/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h) that defines `std::for_each_n`, we see it does not exist.

However, if you have access to libc++, their header from the  [official mirror](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm) does implement `std::for_each_n`.

(Update: the [current version](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h) of the GCC repository now also does include `for_each_n`)

Comment: GCC 8...I am using 8.4 and still have the error during `build` of the ns-3 tool (`configuration` went through). What should I change in the source code or "CMakeLists.txt"?